# Least positive eigenvalue of the BVP $y''-\lambda y'+\frac{2\lambda-1}{x}y=0$, $y(0) = y(1/2) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

> Find the first positive eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the boundary value problem over $x\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$.
>   $$y''-\lambda y'+\frac{2\lambda-1}{x}y=0, \quad y(0)=y(\tfrac{1}{2})=0.$$

My approach: I have tried to use Frobenius Theorem because $x=0$ is a regular-singular point and also the indicial equation implies that the eigenfunction (non-trivial solution) will not a similar form of a Bessel function.

I have managed to use self-adjoint properties but the differential operator of the left hand side turns out to be non self-adjoint.

Comment: This appears to be from a textbook, what textbook was it? I'm curious as I haven't been exposed to this area but it seems awfully close to some of the things I enjoy learning about

Comment: I made this question on my own while I am reading Appell's manuscripts on orthogonal polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing $y(x) = x w(z)$ with $z= \lambda x$, the differential equation is transformed into
$$ z w''(z)+ (2-z) w'(z) -(\lambda^{-1} -1) w(z) =0$$
which is [Kummer's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function). The regular solution to this equation (fulfilling $y(0)=0$) is 
$$ w(z) = {}_1 F_1(\lambda^{-1} -1; 2; z).$$
The first positive eigenvalue, corresponds to the first zero of the function
$$ f(\lambda) = w(\lambda/2).$$

[Numerics shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hypergeometric1F1%5B1%2Fx+-+1%2C+2%2C+x%2F2%5D) that this is situated at $$\lambda \approx 4.60571.$$

Comment: Can you derive the general solution of the ODE using other methods? For example, power series solutions or integrating factors or considering the ODE as a Sturm-Liouville equation?

Comment: Could you clarify why we choose $f(\lambda) = w(\lambda/2)$?

Comment: @user31899: we want to fulfil the boundary condition $y(x=1/2)=0$. Now $x=1/2$ translates to $z=\lambda/2$ and thus we need to have $w(\lambda/2) =0 $.